# Having trouble with java animations

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, jframe

here is my GUIPanel.java file

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    boolean running = false;
    Color startingColor;
    static final int delay = 120000;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    
    GUIPanel() {
        /*int color = random.nextInt(2);
        if(color == 0) {
            startingColor = Color.red; 
        }
        else {
            startingColor = Color.green;
        }*/
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        startSim();
    }

    public void startSim() {
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        //if(running) {
            if(this.getBackground() == Color.green) {
                this.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else {
                this.setBackground(Color.green);
            }
            //delay = delay / 2;
        //}
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

so i've tried to use both the swing timer and the java.util.timer and both result in the same product, which is the gui's background changing colors like a strobe light. I want repaint to be called every 2 minutes and therefore change the background every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I understand now the draw function is always looping so I need to make a new method to change the background to get the time to actually work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    boolean running = false;
    Color startingColor;
    static final int delay = 120000;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    
    GUIPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        startSim();
    }

    public void startSim() {
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void changeBackground() {
        if(this.getBackground() == Color.green) {
            this.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            this.setBackground(Color.green);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        changeBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I understand now the draw function is always looping* - not really. What happens is that when you invoke `setBackground()`, the component will automatically invoke repaint() on itself, which will invoke the paintComponent() method which in turn invokes your draw() method. So the issues with your code: 1) a painting method should NOT change a property of the class. The painting method should only paint the current state of the class

Comment: 2) there is no need for your draw() method or to override the paintComponent() method. In your ActionListener code all you need to do is invoked the `setBackground()` method and the component will repaint itself.

Comment: so i edited the code 'fixing' both of the things you said, is this what you mean just take out the draw() and paintcomponent() methods and remove repaint() from the actionPerformed method?

Comment: That is what I was suggesting.